# __new__ is never run on alternate class

Tags: python, class

I am having difficulties with invoking the `__new__` method.

When creating an instance of A(), I want to return an instance of `B()` instead if the input below 10. But the instance is created *without running the `__new__` or `__init__` methods of `B`, why is that?

```
class A (object):
    def __init__ (self, IP, s):
        print 'arrived to init a'
        self.IP=IP
        print self.IP
        print s
    def __new__ (cls, IP, s):
        print "arrived to new a"
        if IP>10:
            self = object.__new__ (cls)
            return self  # return n
        else:
            return super (cls, A).__new__ (B)

class B(object):
    def __init__(self,d,s,ar):
        print 'arrived to b'
        self.ip=d
        print self.ip
        print s
        print ar
    def __new__(cls,d,s,ar):
        print 'arrived to new b' 
        self = object.__new__(cls)
        return self  # return n
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'B({}, ..., ...)'.format(getattr(self, 'ip', '<missing>'))

a = A(10 ,"a")
print a
```

This outputs

```
arrived to new a
B(<missing>, ..., ...)
```

instead of

```
arrived to new a
arrived to new b
arrived to b
10
'a'
?
B(10, ..., ...)
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to give those classes `__new__` methods?

Comment: So why not just return `B()` in `A.__new__`? You should not be passing in `B` in to the `super(cls, A).__new__` method.

Comment: And what would be the 3rd argument to `B`'s constructor when you create an  value.nstance? `A()` only takes 2, you never generate that third.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Hooking into `A.__new__` does let you return a completely different type of object, based on arbitrary rules. Presumably the `B.__new__` is only there to debug why the returned instance is not being initialised.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, fair enough.

Comment: I've edited your question to have a (far) clearer MCVE, one that shows both the actual and the expected output. Note that for the `print ar` line I used `?`, because *you never supplied a value for that variable*. That's why I asked my question about the 3rd argument to `B`'s constructor, and what I used `42` for in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking `object.__new__` to create a new instance here:

```
return super (cls, A).__new__ (B)
```

So `A.__new__` returns an instance of `B()` here, and *because* this returns a new `B()` instance, and not a new `A()` instance, `B.__init__()` will never be called; the types need to match. See the [`object.__new__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where `self` is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to `__new__()`.

`B()` is not an instance of `A` so `__init__` is not called. `B.__new__` is not called because you explicitly bypassed it by asking `object.__new__` to create the instance instead.

Just call `B()` **directly** in your `A.__new__`:

```
    if IP>10:
        self = object.__new__ (cls)
        return self  # return n
    else:
        return B(IP, s, 42)
```

You need to pass in *three arguments*; I made up `42` for the third.

Because `B()` is called, `B.__new__` will be called. Because `B.__new__` returns an instance of `B`, the `__init__` method will also be called.

Demo:

```
>>> A(10 ,"a")
arrived to new a
arrived to new b
arrived to b
10
a
42
B(10, ..., ...)
```